# Do receipt apps like receipt hog automatically sync your online receipts in the background when Wi-fi is on, or do you need to open the app?

Tags: applications, android-12

Even with background activity enabled, do these apps usually need to be opened to sync online receipts, or is it possible for the apps to do so in the background?

Comment: It's totally at the app developer's discretion. And they can change the behavior with every release of the app.

Comment: Thank you, I would assume it's not going to automatically sync as long as I don't allow background usage.